# How can we change allowframebreaks numbering in the title?

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\section{Proposed Methods}
% motivation for creating this theme
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Proposed Methodology}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  % Add line spacing ..
\begin{itemize} 
  \item Datasets : \insertcontinuationtext
        \begin{enumerate} 
                  \item $\text{{Multi Domain Sentiment}}^\text{{[5]}}$ Dataset contains product reviews taken from Amazon.com.
                      \begin{itemize}
                          \item BOOKS : 1000 Positive reviews and 1000 Negative reviews.
                        \end{itemize}
                  \item $\text{{Movie Reviews}}^\text{{[6]}}$ : \\
                      \begin{itemize}
                           \item All html files we collected from the $\text{IMDb archive}^{[7]}$. \\
                            \item 770 Positive reviews and 703 Negative reviews. \\
                      \end{itemize} 
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Preprocessing :
              \begin{enumerate}
                \item \textcolor{violet}{Upper to lower conversion}: All reviews are converted to lower case.

                \item \textcolor{violet}{Normalization} : All word with apostrophies should be replace with its orginal form.     
                \\ eg :$\textcolor{red!=70}{\text{don't} \rightarrow \text{do not}}$

                \item \textcolor{violet}{Non ASCII removal} :  All non ASCII characters are removed from the reviews. \\ eg :$\textcolor{red!=70}{\bigstar \spadesuit \clubsuit \blacklozenge}$

                \item \textcolor{violet}{Remove new lines} : Blank lines are removed from the reviews.

                \item \textcolor{violet}{Stopword removal } : Stopwords in English language are \\ \textcolor{red}{an,are,the,a} etc.To remove all such words we are using Natural Language Toolkit$\text{(NLTK)}^{[8]}$. \\

                \item \textcolor{violet}{Stemming} : A processing of interface for removing morphological affixes from words. eg:$\text{\textcolor{red!=70}{beauty,beautiness,beautiful}}\Rightarrow \text{\textcolor{red!=70}{beauti}} $

              \end{enumerate}
      \item Dataset Partitioning :
          \begin{enumerate}
              \item {\scriptsize {\textbf{MOVIES}}}:
                \begin{figure}
                  \centering
                  \includegraphics[height=1.8cm,width=4cm]{example-image-a}
                  \caption{\scriptsize {Fig 1:Dataset Partitioning of MOVIE reviews}}
                \end{figure}
              \item \scriptsize {\textbf{BOOKS}}:
              \begin{figure}
                  \centering
                  \includegraphics[height=1.8cm,width=4cm]{example-image-b}
                  \caption{\scriptsize {Fig 2: Dataset Partitioning of BOOK reviews}}
                \end{figure}
             \end{enumerate} 
        \item Feature Selection:
            \begin{enumerate}            
                  \item Mutual Infromation :
                  Selects features that are not uniformly distributed among the classes.
                     \begin{equation}
                          \begin{split}
                          MI(F,C_{k})=(\frac{N_{F,C_{k}}}{N}).log(\frac{N.N_{F,C_{k}}}{N_{F}.N_{C_{k}}})+\\
                          (\frac{N_{F,\bar{C_{k}}}}{N}).log(\frac{N.N_{F,\bar{C_{k}}}}{N_{F}.N_{\bar{C_{k}}}})+\\
                          (\frac{N_{\bar{F},C_{k}}}{N}).log(\frac{N.N_{\bar{F},C_{k}}}{N_{\bar{F}}.N_{C_{k}}})+\\
                          (\frac{N_{\bar{F},\bar{C_{k}}}}{N}).log(\frac{N.N_{\bar{F},\bar{C_{k}}}}{N_{\bar{F}}.N_{\bar{C_{k}}}})\;
                          \end{split}
                          \end{equation}
                          \textit{F} depicts the presence of feature \textit{F} \\
                          \textit{$\bar{F}$} is the absence of feature \textit{F} \\
                          \textit{$C_{k}$} is the Positive class \\
                          \textit{$\bar{C_{k}}$} represents Negative class \\
                          \textit{N} depicts Total samples               

            \end{enumerate}

\end{itemize}

% \hyperlink{Architecutre for Sentimental Classification}{\beamerbutton{Diagram}} % Hyperlink...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Each frame displays Proposed Methodology I, Proposed Methodology II, etc..
I want to change it to Proposed Methodology [1/2], Proposed Methodology[2/2], etc.

How can I achieve this output?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, the beamer class does not provide the total number of breaks a slide had with `allowframebreaks`. You can add

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{[\insertcontinuationcount]}
```

to the preamble to get an arabic counter.

And some recommendation from the beamer manual:

- Do not use the option `allowframebreaks` except for long bibliographies.
- Do not use long bibliographies.

So, try to manually divide the content using more frames. I think you will get better results this way. :-)

Comment: if  I dont want the numbers, what I have to do ? kindly explain..@Smarzaro

Comment: Use `\setbeambertemplate{frametitle continuation} {}` to remove the numbers in the frame title

Comment: Typo: in previous comment: `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}`