# How break a frame without roman numbering?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, allowframebreaks

I'm making a presentation with Beamer, and I'm constructing the bibliography.

How do I take out the numbering of frames, when I'm using the `\allowframebreaks`? Like the following:

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, allowframebreaks]

\frametitle{Bibliography}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

.
.
.(References)
.
.

\end{frame}
```

In this case, appears frames entitled "Bibliography I, Bibliography II, ..., Bibliography V", even though I have put `noframenumbering`. I want to remove the Roman numbering. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}`

Comment: It's done that. Very simple that solution, thanks.

Comment: There is a more generic answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212292/135922)

Answer (score 16):

The Roman numbering can be suppressed with

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
```